# Comparing data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have exported CSV files from a Development SQL Server and another from Production.

The table (in the database) has two columns

1. UserID
2. DocumentID

both of these should be unique values.

I want to be able to verify that those two combinations (together) match the other environment.

So far I imported both CSV files in separate worksheets in Excel.
After this, I am not sure what I should do to compare these columns?

I did a little google-ing and there are so many different types of answers but not sure how to do it.

Conditional Formatting only works if I select a single column. I need to get the combination of both columns.

Comment: You could add the records (i.e. the values of the two columns) to a DictionaryObject and iterate over the rows of the second CSV-File to check whether the combinations exist in the DictionaryObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and mildly dirty VBA-approach. I assumed your workbook consists of two worksheets, each containing two columns with headers.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SoftwareIsFun()
Dim wks1 As Worksheet
Dim wks2 As Worksheet
Dim dicObj As Object
Dim lastRow1 As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim i As Long

    Set dicObj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wks1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wks2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    
    With wks1
        lastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastRow1
            If Not dicObj.Exists(.Range("A" & i).Value) Then
                dicObj.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, .Range("B" & i).Value
            Else
                .Range("C" & i).Value = "UserID already exists"
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    With wks2
        lastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastRow2
            If dicObj.Exists(.Range("A" & i).Value) Then
                If .Range("B" & i).Value = dicObj.Item(.Range("A" & i).Value) Then
                    .Rows(i).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Else
                    .Rows(i).Interior.Color = vbRed
                End If
            Else
                .Rows(i).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is something I do daily for my job:

## Step 1

Create a 3rd column in both worksheets called "Key" where you'll concatenate the values for Column's A & B as follows:`=A2&B2`.
Now autofill your rows in column C with the previous formula you've written.

## Step 2

Remove duplicates found in this column you've created, this will effectively preserve pairs and prevent information loss when removing duplicate values. (Data Tab -> Remove Duplicates -> Select column C as the criteria to remove them).

## Step 3

Make a Vlookup in a 4th column in your first worksheet, the function takes 4 parameters: `=vlookup(C2, <4th column of the other worksheet (select entire range from row 2 to end)>, 1, 0)` and autofill your rows with the formula.

If you aren't yet familiar with vlookup yet I strongly advice you watch a brief tutorial on its usage, it is an essential tool to compare data.

Any value that matches will be displayed, whereas an **#N/D** error will print for those which don't match between the 2 tables.